# Showing 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Invalid provider type specified.\n' for RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm using RSA algorithm for encryption and decryption.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new 
X509Certificate2(pfxFilePath,password);
RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key;
```

Working properly on local-machine/service but showing  Invalid provider type specified.\n' on sever machine.Using same .net framework.
How can resolve the issue.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding some parameters works in certificate works for me.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxFilePath,password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```